# How to add or active a one-time listener in firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a listener to a document change in firestore. Somehow the listener was triggered multiple times, but I just want to run the code that was triggered by the listener once. Basically I want to remove the listener after it was triggered once. How can I do that? Thanks

update:
Here is the code I want to use:

```
db.collection("cities").document("SF")
 .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
   guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
     print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
     return
   }
   print("Current data: \(document.data())")
   //my other code
 }
```

The listener may be triggered many times. I only want "my other code" to be executed once, namely for the first time the listener is triggered.

Comment: Calling `getDocument()` should read the document once. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document. If that doesn't work for you, update your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can have a look.

Comment: I want to read the document when it was updated at the first time. So I add a listener to the document. But the listener will be triggered multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
let count = 0
let registration = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
 .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
   count = count + 1
   if count == 2 registration.remove()
   guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
     print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
     return
   }
   print("Current data: \(document.data())")
   //my other code
 }
```

Comment: I assume you want to use var count = 0 at the the first line. Another issue is: I got an error message in Xcode: Variable used within its own initial value. It seems I can't not use unsubscibe() inside the listener.

Comment: I didn't have xcode handy to test, so decided it might be more useful to answer with an approach, instead of waiting until I have more time. Feel free to edit the answer to fix such mistakes. Note that I fixed another problem: on [iOS the way to remove a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Protocols/ListenerRegistration) is different from Web.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to listen the document change.

```
/// Add listener to query
listener = db.collection("cities").document("SF").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
     /// Check if snapshot is not nil
      guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
           print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
           return
      }

      /// Check if snapshot has documents and not empty
      guard snapshot.documents.last != nil else {
           // The collection is empty.
           return
      }

      /// This is the on change listner  
      snapshot.documentChanges.forEach({ (diff) in
           print(diff.document.data())
           if (diff.type == .added) {

           }
           else if (diff.type == .modified) {

           }
           else if (diff.type == .removed) {

           }
      })
}
```

Now you have the instance of `listener` and you can stop listening it anytime.

```
listener.remove()
```

BTW for single time use you should use `getDocuments(completion:)` it calls once.

**EDIT: `getDocuments(completion:)` example**

```
queryRef.whereField(key, isEqualTo: value).getDocuments(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
    if let _error = error {
        print (_error.localizedDescription)
        return;
    }

    guard let _querySnapshot = querySnapshot else {
          print("querySnapshot is nil")
          return;
    }

    for document in _querySnapshot.documents {
        print(document.data())
    }
})
```

Comment: Would you please provide an example for getDocuments(completion:)? I would like to have a document read when there is an update, not directly read it. On the other hand, I want to only read it once.

Comment: @FredXie See Edit part of answer for `getDocuments(completion:)` example.

Comment: Original answer already describes your requirement. Just setup a for required node and `listener` will let you know if there is change  by `(.modified)` condition. What else your problem is? And after first notification you can remove this `listener` as mentioned in my answer so that it will call just once.

Comment: @FredXie Please accept any answer if your problem has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry didn't come back to this for a while. Although the google's website show that you can use .docuementChange, and .type, but they are not really supported yet. Thank you anyway. Later I found I can solve the problem with the answer given by Frank, although not like what he give exactly, because I can't use .move() inside the listener. But I can do what I want with a condition of count==1 (for example).